# Using autocomplete.ModelSelect2 with htmx functionality

Tags: django, htmx

I have a form in Django. Then, however, I tried to add autocomplete functionality. The search bar/autocomplete itself works, but the hx-get never fires the courses/ url.

```py
# Version 1: Works as expected
department = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Department.objects.order_by("name"),
    initial=Department.objects.order_by("name").first(),
    widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={
            "class": "custom-select mb-4",
            "autocomplete": "off",
            "hx-get": "/courses/",
            "hx-target": "#id_course",
        }
    ),
)


# Version 2: Does not work
department = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Department.objects.order_by("name"),
    initial=Department.objects.order_by("name").first(),
    widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
        url="department-autocomplete",
        attrs={
            "class": "custom-select mb-4",
            "autocomplete": "off",
            "hx-get": "/courses/",
            "hx-trigger": "change",
            "hx-target": "#id_course",
        },
    ),
)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand why the second version doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/) I suspect you want `changed` as your trigger, rather than `change`.